# Using @JsonIdentityInfo along with @JsonSerialize with a custom converter

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialise an object by converting it first to another object. At the same time I do not want to serialise twice the same object so I am using @JsonIdentityReference to serialise it only the first time. However since the converter will always create a new output object for the same input object the entire object is serialised every time. Is there a way to avoid serialising twice the same object while at the same time using a converter?

### The Domain class

```java
@JsonSerialize(converter = BooleanWithNameConverter.class)
@JsonDeserialize(converter = BooleanWithNameDtoConverter.class)
public class BooleanWithName {

    private final boolean value;
    private final String name;
    
    BooleanWithName(String name, boolean value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

### The DTO

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class)
public class BooleanWithNameDto {

    private final boolean value;
    private final String name;
    
    @JsonCreator
    BooleanWithNameDto(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("value") boolean value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

### The converter to the DTO

```java
public class BooleanWithNameConverter extends StdConverter<BooleanWithName, BooleanWithNameDto> {

    @Override
    public BooleanWithNameDto convert(BooleanWithName obj) {
        return new BooleanWithNameDto(obj.getName(), obj.getValue());
    }
}
```

### The converter back to the domain object

This is not strictly needed since the problem can be seen just by examining the json string but helpful in order to add a small unit test demonstrating the problem

```java
public class BooleanWithNameDtoConverter extends StdConverter<BooleanWithNameDto, BooleanWithName> {

    @Override
    public BooleanWithName convert(BooleanWithNameDto obj) {
        return new BooleanWithName(obj.getName(), obj.getValue());
    }
}
```

### A small unit test that fails

```java
public class UnitTest {

    @Test
    public void testConverter() throws JsonProcessingException {
        BooleanWithName booleanWithName = new BooleanWithName("dummy", true);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        BooleanWithName[] value = { booleanWithName, booleanWithName };
        BooleanWithName[] readValue = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value), BooleanWithName[].class);
        Assertions.assertEquals(readValue[0], readValue[1]);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.